# Why was Avra the first Green Lantern?

Tags: plot-explanation, emerald-knights

I was watching *Green Lantern: Emerald Knights* and something got me wondered. When Hal told Arisia the story of how everything began, he said Avra was the first Green Lantern. However, he was the 4<sup>th</sup> of the batch to receive the rings. Isn't the first person to receive the ring supposed to be the first Green Lantern?

Comment: Not seen the film myself but [wiki](http://greenlanterns.wikia.com/wiki/Avra) say he got his ring differently then others, so maybe Hal was referring to that fact.

Comment: I haven't seen it, but maybe he was just the first to use the title "Green Lantern."  If the others called themselves Ringman or Super Gleep-glorp (or whatever) then they weren't the first Green Lantern.

Comment: Is it to do with Avra being the first one to create a construct?

Comment: @sirjonsnow I don't recall Avra using the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avra was the first chosen for her will power,  by the ring, instead of just strength. She was the first to realise the rings are powered by the green spectrum of light, of Will Power. She was the first to use the ring with will power and conjured the first green lantern construct, the sword. Which the others then learned to do in her footsteps.

She might not be the chronological first, but she is the first in spirit. The first to use the real power of the green lanterns.